# Changing Single Digit Integer Input to Ordinal Numbers

Tags: python

Problem 2 of Lesson Nine on Computer Science Circles asks the user to change a single digit number input to its ordinal adjective using only 4 separate if / elif cases. Here is my following code which is giving me '1th' instead of '1st'..

```
x = input()
if x == 1:
    print (1+'st')
elif x == 2:
    print (x+'nd')
elif x == 3:
    print (x+'rd')
else:
    print (x+'th')
```

If I change the `x = input()`to `x = int(input())` it gives me the following error:

> TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'

Comment: You can't concatenate an integer and a string. You have to use something like `str.format()` or call `str()` on the integer while concatenating it to the string. Also, I'm assuming this is Python 3 because `input()` returns a string. You can just do `if int(x) == 1:` to get around that.

Comment: @michaelpri i'm trying `if int(x) == 1:` along with changing the rest of the elif cases and its not working. im confused on the other info gave. . can you give examples please? :)

Comment: Also note that `21th` isn't good.

Comment: @erip this is for single digit numbers only.

Comment: @Raylon that's not what your code says.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the comments suggest, you cannot combine a integer with a string. 
However, you *can* add a string to another string.

Here is what I mean:

When you try to combine an number with string, i.e. `1 + 'st'`, you get a`TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'`

However, if you try to combine an number *typecasted* to a string with another, like `str(1) + 'st'`, you get the desired output, `1st`.

Similarly, in your code, you have `x + 'st'`, which is illegal addition between an integer and a string. Instead, try printing a typecasted version of `x`, which I have called `x_str`:

```
x = int(input())
x_str = str(x)

if x == 1:
    print (x_str+'st')
elif x == 2:
    print (x_str+'nd')
elif x == 3:
    print (x_str+'rd')
else:
    print (x_str+'th')
```

Comment: tyvm for the help! I appreciate it and understand what youre saying now. But, using that code is still giving me the following error from the website test: Did not pass tests. Please check details below and try again.
Results for test case 1 out of 5 - Input: 1, Program executed without crashing.
Program output: 1th. Expected this correct output:
1st.

Comment: Yah, this code only works in Python2. But as you said, it did output 1th on python3. I just revised the code for python3, it should work now.

Comment: Glad it helped! Does it work now? If so, just click the "check" mark to show that you have resolved this thread. :)